# Throttle event produced from EventProducerType - Swift Bond

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to throttle the event produced from an `EventProducerType` of the [SwiftBond](https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond) framework.

Here is how I'm testing how to throttle an event:

```
var throttledObserver: EventProducer<String?>!

init() {
  throttledObserver = Observable<String?>(nil).throttle(1000, queue: Queue.Main)      

  throttledObserver.observeNew { text in
    // This is always printed no matter how large the throttle time interval is
    print(text)
  }
}

// UISearchBarDelegate method
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
  throttledObserver.next(searchText)
}
```

With this approach, there is no throttling and the text is printed immediately upon text change. My goal is to throttle the search text of a UISearchBar to make network requests to retrieve some data from an endpoint.

Comment: I got it to work with the following:

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following:

```
var throttledObserver = Observable<String?>!

init() {
  throttledObserver = Observable<String?>(nil)

  // the key is not to save the returned value from throttle into a variable, but to set the observation immediately
  throttledObserver.throttle(1000, queue: Queue.Main)
    .observeNew { text in
      print(text)
    }
}

// UISearchBarDelegate method
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
  throttledObserver.next(searchText)
}
```